# regexp to find after 4th occurrence

Tags: regex, wordpress

I using REGEXP in wp_query.
I am storing post meta as **20181020 (yyyymmdd)**
so basically I want a REGEXP so that I can filter if user enter 10 (mm) in filter box

currently I am using this `'^'.$date` but this only works if user entered yyyymm format.
I want to search this if use enter value in either yyyy or mm there is no need for dd.

I want to filter based on user input.

User will select month or year,
for example, if user select Dec month then i will get response 10. Then i pass this value in meta_query.
here is the meta query. But in this issue is data stored in post meta is in yyyymmdd format. So I want a regexp where I can query to 4th occurrence.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'achievements',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'achievement_date',
        'value' => '^'.$date,
        'compare' => 'REGEXP'
        )
    )
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: can you give us example input and expected output?

Comment: Your title is really unclear! And the question too!

Comment: @Toto basically i want to search with regexp, and I want in such a way that it skip first 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
i just need to use this `^....` expression. This will skip first 4 characters.